# spark_sklearn GridSearchCV __init__ failed with parameter error

Tags: python, apache-spark, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I am trying to use spark_sklearn.GridSearchCV, but got **init** parameter error.

```
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (4 given)
```

This is the code:

```
from spark_sklearn import GridSearchCV

gsearch2 = GridSearchCV(estimator=ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(**params), param_grid=param_test2, n_jobs=1)
```

If I give more parameters to `GridSearchCV`, such as add `cv=5`, then the error become

```
TypeError: __init__() takes at least 4 arguments (5 given)
```

Any suggestion?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`GridSearchCV.__init__` takes [3 obligatory arguments](https://github.com/databricks/spark-sklearn/blob/be52d74df746fac1b2e02227283d5637e066932a/python/spark_sklearn/grid_search.py#L240):

- `sc` - `SparkContext`.
- `estimator`
- `param_grid`.

You forgot the `SparkContext`:

```
GridSearchCV(
    sc=SparkContext.getOrCreate(),
    estimator=ensemble.GradientBoostingRegressor(**params), 
    param_grid=param_test2, n_jobs=1)
```